# Bloomberg - Refresh Workbook how to call

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I would like to know if there was a way to do :

```
Bloomberg - > Refresh Workbook
```

[image]

But not with my hand and in VBA or using something else.. :

`Workbook.calculate` does not work some times formula gets `#N/A Requesting Data...` because Data aren't loaded on time..

I really need to found a 100% working way to do it, else if it fail sometimes it can be a huge problem

Comment: Since this looks like to be an add-in you would need to check the documentation of that  add-in *if* and *how* it can be used with VBA. Or if the add-in source code can be viewed (and is not locked) you can investigate it yourself to find out which procedure to call.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I will try to found something and let you know if you are interested

Comment: @Pᴇʜ But there is no way to simulate this click ?

Comment: No, you could try to use the [CommandBars.ExecuteMso method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso) to run a command from the ribbon. But therefore you would need to know the `idMso` of that button, which you either get from the documentation of the add-in or its source code.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ There is no way to browse Ribon and to display them all into a list ?

Comment: not that I know of.

Comment: Try `Application.run "RefreshAllWorkbooks"`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It does not work, there is a kind of timeout so sometime data aren't loaded and excel think all calculation are done... Do you think that I should Post an other issue and then ask if a way exist to get all Ribbon element ?

Comment: Did you try that? `Application.run "RefreshAllWorkbooks"` should call the function of the bloomberg refresh button in the ribbon.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ That seems working, how did you manage to found this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following procedures in the bloomberg add-in

[image]

```
Application.Run "RefreshCurrentSelection"
```

[image]

```
Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorksheet"
```

[image]

```
Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorkbook"
```

[image]

```
Application.Run "RefreshAllWorkbooks"
```

[image]

```
Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"    
Application.Run "RefreshData"
```

For the `CurrentSelection` you would have to select the desired data first

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("YourData").Select
Application.Run "RefreshCurrentSelection"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I think your answer will help a lot of Bloomberg users, Hope my issue will be easy to find

Comment: @Dorian Added the rest of them, give them a try.

Comment: All work but `Application.Run "RefreshData"` seems to do the same as `Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorkbook"`