# Thomson Reuters EIKON -> Refresh Workbook how to call

Tags: excel, vba, thomson-reuters-eikon

I would like to know if there was a way refresh EIKON data thanks to VBA :

```
EIKON- > Refresh Workbook
```

[image]

**NOTE** `Application.Calculate` isn't the answer excepted.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61814900/bloomberg-refresh-workbook-how-to-call(Quite similar post here for bloomberg)

Comment: https://community.developers.refinitiv.com/questions/20247/can-you-please-send-me-the-excel-vba-code-which-ex.html maybe? Don't have Eikon so can't test.

Comment: @BigBen Ty didn't found it on my own

Answer (score 0):

To run the macros automatically when the Excel sheet is opened, you can use the Workbook_Open event. Here's the VBA code:

You can copy and paste this code into a VBA module in your Excel workbook. To do this:

Press Alt + F11 to open the Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) editor.
Insert a new module by right-clicking on any item in the Project Explorer window, selecting "Insert," and then choosing "Module."
Copy and paste the provided code into the module.
Close the VBA editor.
Now, you can run the RefreshEikonData macro from Excel, and it will execute the four commands you specified.

```
Sub RunRefreshEikonData()
    ' Command 1: Refresh Selection
    Application.Run "EikonRefreshSelection"

    ' Command 2: Refresh Worksheet
    Application.Run "EikonRefreshWorksheet"

    ' Command 3: Refresh Workbook
    Application.Run "EikonRefreshWorkbook"

    ' Command 4: Refresh All
    Application.Run "EikonRefreshAll"
End Sub
```

To add the Workbook_Open event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        RunRefreshEikonData
    End Sub
```

Press Alt + F11 to open the Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) editor.
In the Project Explorer window, find and select "ThisWorkbook" under "Microsoft Excel Objects."
Paste the Workbook_Open event code into the code window for "ThisWorkbook."

Please refer
https://community.developers.refinitiv.com/questions/20247/can-you-please-send-me-the-excel-vba-code-which-ex.html